# deboostrap overlay-like/union filesystem and network boot?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, debootstrap

I'll describe the situation first: I'm trying to create a network booted Linux (Debian) for about 200 workstations. Unfortunately, those workstations become hardware-heterogenous in previous years; for example, I have several generation of nVidia GPUs which cannot be used with a single nVidia driver.

My idea is to create (using `debootstrap`) a Linux system which would be booted over the network and all directories would be mounted using NFS (all things will be in the RAM, so I cannot have this downloaded to each machine; also, the amount of software will be huge, about 30-40 GB).

And the problem: I'm searching for a solution that would allow to have a base filesystem with all software and stuff (installed using `debootstrap`, laying on a NFS server) and then to have a way to *add* during boot, for example, directory containing modern nVidia drivers for the newest Quadros, or other directory containing legacy nVidia drivers, or an option to not add a nVidia drivers at all and use `nouveau`. In other words: load base system common to all options and then some files for the selected option.

When someone (a student) would boot a machine, a `syslinux` would be booted and options showed, for example: "Debian Stable", "Debian Machine Learning", etc. which would load different components required for the job.

To sum up: is there a way to have a large base system with separate additions that can be added/mounted-maybe-overlay-like? I can create of course several `debootstrap`ped system, but each would have 30-40 GBs in size, from which 98% would be the same in each of them :)

Best Regards
Kamil

Comment: I don't think this will work, because video kernel drivers need to be available really really early in the boot process. If RAM is at premium, and you can't include all video kernel drivers, at least for the video drivers I'd rather make a build system that can automatically create different initial images with different video drivers from some base image, and decide by MAC address etc. which host should get which image.

Comment: This is what I want to bypass :) I can generate several distributions with different packages, but the problem is that they will have 98% the same content/packages. If i generate 3 versions, each 40 GBs, only 2-3 GBs will be different and rest will be redundant.